# Overrride Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price problem

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, overrides

I have noobie problem. I want to rewrite the class `Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`. I made a module `SpartakusMd_MageOverride`, but it doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is in `config.xml` or in file path or maybe there should be more files, like a controller.

File `/app/etc/modules/SpartakusMd_MageOverride.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SpartakusMd_MageOverride>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </SpartakusMd_MageOverride>
    </modules>
</config>
```

File `app/code/local/SpartakusMd/MageOverride/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SpartakusMd_MageOverride>
            <version>
                0.1.0
            </version>
        </SpartakusMd_MageOverride>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <layer_filter_price>SpartakusMD_MageOverride_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price</layer_filter_price>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

File `/app/code/local/SpartakusMd/MageOverride/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php`:

```
class SpartakusMD_MageOverride_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price {

    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        die('inside');
    }

}
```

**Edit**

I forgot to add `<rewrite>` xml tag. But now I have another problem a include error.

```
Warning: include(SpartakusMD/MageOverride/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/clients/client1/web97/web/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Path was wrong. The correct one is `app/code/local/SpartakusMd/MageOverride/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php`